# User first time login shows error Null Reference exception

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity

I have created a project in asp.net core for erp purposes. In it I have an option to create a new user. While logging in, the claims are added using the below code in login controller

```
                List<Claim> AllClaims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim("UserId", userdetails.UserId.ToString()),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userdetails.LoginName),
                    new Claim("FullName", userdetails.FirstName + " " + userdetails.LastName),
                    new Claim("ChurchId", userdetails.ChurchId.ToString()),
                    new Claim("Email", userdetails.Email),
                    new Claim("ChurchName", userdetails.Church.Name),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role1),
                };

                var resultClaims = await userManager.RemoveClaimsAsync(IdenUser, AllClaims);
                resultClaims = await userManager.AddClaimsAsync(IdenUser, AllClaims);
```

Since the user is in his first time login the view is redirected to the Change password screen.
The change password controller method is given below.

```
    public IActionResult ChangePasswordIndex()
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
        var currentUserId = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser.FindFirst("UserId").Value);
        var churchId = Convert.ToInt32(currentUser.FindFirst("ChurchId").Value);
        var Role = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role).Value;

        string userId = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        return View();
    }
```

In the above method I am trying to access the current user using this.User. Since there are no claims in it the next line code gives error.
When the user login is not the first time it works comfortable. How can I access the current user details?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that have truly logged in with a user, I can't see your full code.

Or try use this to get the current user:

```
YourUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

It also could be caused when AnonymousAuthentication is enabled, you can try to open launchsettings.json

and set

```
"iisSettings": {
   "windowsAuthentication": true,
   "anonymousAuthentication": false,
   //...
```

And you can also check this link to get the current user:

https://www.thecodebuzz.com/get-current-user-name-asp-net-core/

Comment: HttpContext.User returns null. So the await userManager.GetUserAsync method cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

Put claims above the usermanager.PasswordSignIn().
Then the claims are accessible in the next controller of the project.